# Sorting data from Importrange with query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm currently solving a data transport problem. I have two tables A (source) and B into which data is overwritten based on a condition. I would like the newly imported data into table B to be sorted under itself and not according to the initial structure in table A. Any idea how to create this rule in table B on google sheets ?

Thank you in advance for the answer.

I've tried scripts, but I can't do them at all. I wanted to get the newly imported data to line up underneath each other, so that she could add more notes to the rows without the import of new rows messing up the data.

[A- Source table, if column D is "ANO", the data is imported into table B.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H2zb.png)

[In this table I want the newly imported data to be sorted in descending order. Not in order in table A.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIXzu.png)

Comment: Why ask about Google sheets and tag Excel? Can you also share some samples or screenshots to show what you mean and share your attempt(s)?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I added print screens to the post.

Comment: ```=QUERY(YOUR_RANGE,"WHERE Col4='ANO' ORDER BY Col1 DESC")```